# How to store the line matching an expression in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following code, and i am wanting to store the entire line that contains the matching expression, but currently i am able to store only the expression itself.

```
expr='\hello';
fileread = regexp(filetext, expr, 'match');
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n',fileread{:});
```

suppose my file contains:

```
 Hello,my name is X
 X hello 
Not this line
```

my file data.txt stores

```
hello
hello
```

instead of the entire line containing the expression.
desired data.txt

```
Hello,my name is X
     X hello
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the format of `filetext`?

Comment: What do you expect your data.txt file to contain? Do you understand what the `regexp` function is doing?

Comment: data_files = 'hello.lnt';
A = textread(data_files, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
filetext = fileread(data_files);

I expect data.txt to contain the entire line that contains the expr.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way you are interacting with the regexp function I will assume you have all the file text in a single variable.  Let's imagine that variable takes the following form:

```
my name is hello there
Hello,my name is X
 X hello
 Not this line
```

For your reference, I've constructed this variable using `sprintf`

```
string = sprintf('my name is hello there\nHello,my name is X\n X hello\n Not this line')
```

You can extract the lines which have hello with the following regexp:

```
[~,~,~,d] = regexp(string, '.*?[H|h]ello.*?\n')
```

The results can be retrieved from the cell array with:

```
>> d{1}

ans =

my name is hello there


>> d{2}

ans =

Hello,my name is X


>> d{3}

ans =

 X hello
```

Note that I used a couple of lazy quantifiers `.*?`, check out *Laziness Instead of Greediness* at this link if you would like to learn more: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is not using the MATLAB `regexp` function correctly. If you look under "Return Substrings using 'match' Keyword" on this [site](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html), you will see that the result you got is what is expected for what your code stated (it returns the parts of the input string that match the regular expression you supplied). I was going to post a suggestion, but someone beat me to it ;-). Good luck.